# SQL - print records which are given by user in string variable

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

How to use user defined variable in a String query to get a specific record in sql query string statement.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 
System.out.println("Enter the name you want to find the details");
String x = sc.nextLine();

//john is entered
//String x = "john";

try{
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       String query = "select * from employee where name="+x;
       rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
     while(rs.next())
      {
       System.out.print(rs.getString("sl_no"));
       System.out.print(rs.getString("name"));
       System.out.print(rs.getString("address"));
      }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}



Output : ERROR : column "john" does not exist
```

john is a record in the table under name column and is not a column itself.

I would like that particular record to be printed having name as john which is taken as a user input.

Comment: Use a PreparedStatement https://mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the missing quotes sign:

```
String query = "select * from employee where name='"+x + "'";
```

But I suggest to use the prepareStatement instead as its more secured and also much more useful with parameters injection

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from employee where name=?");
stmt.setString(1, x);
```